# Starting a script in a Desktop icon

Tags: lubuntu, scripts, icons, xfce

I have the following .desktop file on my Desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Name=Robomongo
 Comment=Launch Robomongo
 Exec=/usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin/robomongo.sh
 Icon=/usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/share/icons/robomongo.png
 Type=Application
 Terminal=true
```

I want the application to start up with a terminal window. When I click it it opens a terminal window but doesn't acatually run the script. How can I set that up? If I make "Terminal=false", then it starts the program with no terminal window. I also tried creating a link, but don't get a terminal window.

I'm also having a problem with this icon.  It keeps giving me a "Invalid desktop entry file: '/home/dev/Desktop/mongod-port-27007.desktop" error.  mongod works from the shell.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=mongod-port-27007
Comment=Launch Robomongo
Exec=mongod
Icon=/usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/share/icons/robomongo.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same desktop file definition and it works as expected for me. So double check that the launcher script has the right permissions:

```
chmod u+x /usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin/robomongo.sh
```

Alternatively you may try the following `Exec` command:

```
Exec=bash /usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin/robomongo.sh
```

Comment: Adding +x made the script work. But it doesn't work for compiled commands like "mongod".  Also, for the first one, when I switch to Terminal=true, I get a terminal come up, but the command doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=xfce4-terminal -x /usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin/robomongo.sh
Icon=/usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/share/icons/robomongo.png
Name=Robomongo
Comment=Launch Robomongo
```

and give the read permission with `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/share/icons/robomongo.png && /usr/local/robomongo-0.8.4-i386/bin/robomongo.sh`.

The diference is that I execute the terminal with option -x:

> "−x, −−execute; −e, −−command=comanda; −−working−directory=directori;"

And I added

```
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

I have a script in gnome desktop and lxde desktop running with those so I hope it work for you too, but in gnome I use:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x sudo /usr/local/bin/donacion.sh
```

And for lxde or lubuntu:

```
Exec=lxterminal -e sudo /usr/local/bin/donacion.sh
```

Tell me if it worked, thx.